# How to ping feature in openlayers?

Tags: openlayers

I have never seen this but I suppose **openlayers** has this feature and I just cant find its name.

I'd like specific feature to somehow let user know where it is. Probably flash for a moment.

Any built-in features for that?

Comment: Nothing built in but it can be done as in  https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-animation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly what you want and it can be done as in:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-animation.html